# How to create a dict/object/mapping in an aggregation field

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `groupedby` object in pandas:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(by=['resolution','media_type', 'asset_type']).file_name
print (type(df_grouped))
# <class 'pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy'>
```

It looks something like this if I apply a list:

```
print (df_grouped.apply(list))
# resolution  media_type  asset_type
# HD          Video       Feature       [LG_ALPH02...
#                         Promo         [Alpha&ch.mov]
#                         Trailer       [LG_ALP178_2...
# Name: file_name, dtype: object
```

However, I would like to be able to create a mapping in the right-most column so that I can keep some of the values grouped together. For example, instead of having a list of `file_name`s in the right column, to have an object of format `{file_name: md5}` (note: I have a field called `md5` in my dataframe). In this way, I could do an iteration such as:

```
for keys, value_obj in df_grouped.apply(...).items():
    for filename, md5 in value_obj.items():
        print (filename, '-->', md5)
```

How could I do this? (come to think of it, it would also be pretty neat to create something like a `class` or custom object to be able to pass to the `apply(...)` if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first omit `file_name` after `groupby`, because need processing also `md5` column. Then use lambda function for convert columns to dictionaries per groups, output is `Series`:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(by=['resolution','media_type', 'asset_type'])

series = df_grouped.apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['file_name'],x['md5'])))
```

Or:

```
series = df_grouped.apply(lambda x: dict(x[['file_name','md5']].to_numpy()))
```

**Sample**:

```
print (df)
  resolution media_type asset_type             file_name  md5
0         HD      Video    Feature  LG_ALPHAASP_EN__L102    1
1         HD      Video      Promo        Alphap_2ch.mov    2
2         HD      Video    Trailer            LG_ALPHAX9    3
3         HD      Video    Trailer      LG_ALPHAX9_178_2    4



df_grouped = df.groupby(by=['resolution','media_type', 'asset_type'])
    
series = df_grouped.apply(lambda x: dict(x[['file_name','md5']].to_numpy()))
print (series)
resolution  media_type  asset_type
HD          Video       Feature                    {'LG_ALPHAASP_EN__L102': 1}
                        Promo                            {'Alphap_2ch.mov': 2}
                        Trailer       {'LG_ALPHAX9': 3, 'LG_ALPHAX9_178_2': 4}
dtype: object
```